# Mocking Functions with Vitest

Tags: javascript, testing, vitest

I have an issue where I'm trying to test an exported method in a file.  I need to test the `handleFilesData` method, which has calls to other functions within the same file.  I'd like to mock the return values of those other methods.

My file, called `basic.ts` is as follows:

```
# basic.ts

const handleDataItems = async () => {
  console.log('REAL handleDataItems');
  const data = await handleData();
  return data;
};

export const handleData = async () => {
  console.log('REAL handleData');
  return 'REAL handleData result';
};

export const handleFilesData = async () => {
  console.log('REAL handleFilesData');
  const result = await handleDataItems();
  return result;
};
```

My test is then trying to mock the return value of `handleData`

```
# basic.test.ts

import { assert, describe, expect, it } from 'vitest';
import { handleFilesData } from '../src/basic.js';

vi.mock('../src/basic', async () => {
  const actual = await vi.importActual('../src/basic');

  return {
    ...actual,
    handleData: vi.fn().mockReturnValue('FooBar'),
  };
});

describe('Test Functions', () => {
  it('handles File Data Correctly', async () => {
    const result = await handleFilesData();

    expect(result).toBe('FooBar');
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I'm still seeing the real `handleData` method being called:

```
Test Functions > handles File Data Correctly
REAL handleFilesData
REAL handleDataItems
REAL handleData
```

[Vitest mentions this pitfall](https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#mocking-pitfalls), but I don't know how else to test this function or restructure the code to make it more easily testable.

I've tried moving the `handleData` method to a separate file and importing it into the `basic.ts` file, but that doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question and not just state a broad topic. See [ask] and take the [tour].